# How to change case of latin UTF-8 strings in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, utf-8

In Objective-C, it's dead simple:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"BAÑO" lowercaseString]);  // Outputs "baño".
```

**In C++, what's the equivalent?** Can anyone provide valid code for this that produces the same output? Is there a nice STL way to do this without relying on ICU, Boost, or any other 3rd party libs?

My current non-solution is:

```
using namespace std;
string s = "BAÑO";
wstring w(s.begin(), s.end());
transform(w.begin(), w.end(), w.begin(), towlower);
// w contains "baÑo"
```

Comment: write your own function http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/70692/

Comment: Your current non-solution looks pretty decent to me!

Comment: @fluffy I agree! I'd wrap this "non-solution" into a helper function, and call it a pretty darn good solution.

Comment: My non-solution outputs "baÑo" instead of "baño". Are you guys seeing something I'm not?

Comment: @liutenantdan: `towlower` will depend on your current locale, so it's quite possible that some people do get "baño". I.e. it's more a problem with your locale than with your code snippet.

Comment: The initialization of `w` silently assumes ISO-8859-1 -> ISO646 (Latin1 -> Unicode) BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turns out to be incredibly complicated in C++. There's only one library I know of that gets it absolutely right taking into consideration unicode normalization and other non-lower-128-ASCII character point issues.

[IBM's ICU](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/)

It's massive but it does everything correctly. toupper and tolower fall short in this issue unfortunately and there's no other C++ construct available.

Comment: The question explicitly ruled out ICU.

Comment: @Adrian True, but it seems that the reality of the situation trumps the question. NSString in objc is an array of unicode characters and it uses ICU under the hood. In this case, in pure C++, I would essentially have to incorporate ICU to get the same functionality.  (Luckily, my target platforms are iOS and Android, so really I could just have separate _ios and _android implementation files that bridge to their respective platforms: objc, and java).

Answer (score 2):

There is [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/tolower/), which is locale specific, but I don't think it'll work with UTF-8 strings.

The correct solution will always be locale specific, because the case rules depend on the language.  For example, the lowercase version of 'I' is not always 'i'.

Comment: The problem with `tolower`, `towlower`, etc., is that they assume a one-to-one correspondence between input and output characters.  That doesn't work for Unicode because of mappings like upper("ß") = "SS", and that's not even considering that the characters themselves are variable-length in UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @dan04: Are there any characters whose upper- and lower-case encodings differ in length? That would appear only in UTF-8 anyway, as UTF-16 encodes the BMP in 16 bits and the SMP doesn't have upper or lower-case characters.

Comment: @dan04:  Yes, there are limitations to tolower, but the question explicitly asked for a standard library solution and ruled out third-party libraries.  Thus this is the best you can do with those requirements.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, for example `Ɑ` and `ɑ` are an upper/lower pair with different-length encodings in UTF-8 (`E2 B1 AD` and `C9 91`).  And Plane 1 does have upper/lower-case characters (Deseret alphabet), although I am unaware of any cross-plane casing rules.

Comment: @Adrian:  Forgive my lack of knowledge of C++ locales, but in your answer could you include sample code that achieves what I'm looking for assuming the language is always Spanish?  Would "tolower" be reliable if I know for a fact that the language is exclusively Spanish, and no other language?

Comment: @liutenantdan: You may have an issue with `ǁ` (U+01C1). That uppercases to `LL` I think?